# jQuery UI autocomplete with UTF8 characters

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Is there a way can I prevent [jQuery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) results from displaying UTF8 characters as a black square with a "?" inside?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $text = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['term']);
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT field_63 FROM jbd_joomd_type15 WHERE field_63 LIKE '%$text%' ORDER BY field_63 ASC";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    $json = '[';
    $first = true;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        if (!$first) { $json .=  ','; } else { $first = false; }
        $json .= '{"value":"'.$row['field_63'].'"}';
    }
    $json .= ']';
    echo $json;
?>
```

My jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#field_63').autocomplete(
    {
        source: "cities.php",
        minLength: 1
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `json_encode` on your data?

[See documentation here: json_encode — Returns the JSON representation of a value](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Also you did not share your jQuery code???

I also found [this discussion on jQuery autocomplete and special character encoding](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-autocomplete-special-character-encoding).

Comment: I am absolutely new to json scripts and I found a few results on the internet about the issue, however none of the code examples I found looks like mine, so I'm afraid I'll mess up my code if I do something wrong. That's why I asked for help. Thank you I'll take a look at the links you posted.

Comment: I will retag your question so that more people will see it, and hopefully give you more options.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by replacing the line

```
$json .= '{"value":"'.$row['field_63'].'"}';
```

with

```
$json .= '{"value":"'.utf8_encode($row['field_63']).'"}';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same...

All my php sites are utf-8 encoded, the MYSQL database also. Everywhere looks good and shows the proper characters, but this autocomplete list.
At the return value I needed to use this.

```
utf8_encode(return_value) ;
```

This solved the problem.